# Kotlin class is returning false before it has finished

Tags: android, kotlin

In my main activity i have a function that runs once the login button it pressed. I'm calling a class that attempts to login via an API which takes a second or two to run. However, when i'm calling the login class it seems to be threaded and doesn't wait for the login to complete and returns false which is the default. Example code is as follows:

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

        fun loginBtnClicked(view: View) {

        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        // get domain info
        val domain: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.loginDomain)
        val domainUrl = domain.text.toString()
        val url = "$domainUrl/api/"

        // get username info
        val username = loginUsername
        // get password info
        val password = loginPassword

        if (ApiGet(
                url = url,
                username = username.text.toString(),
                password = password.text.toString()
            ).login()) {
            println("It worked")
            val dashboard = Intent(this, DashboardActivity::class.java)
            Consts.DOMAIN = url
            Consts.USERNAME = username.text.toString()
            Consts.PASSWORD = password.text.toString()
            startActivity(dashboard)
        } else {
            println("It didn't work")
            progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            runOnUiThread {
                Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "runOnUiThread")
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    "Please check the domain, username and password then try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
}


class ApiGet(val url: String, val username: String = Consts.USERNAME, val password: String = Consts.PASSWORD) {

    fun login(): Boolean {

        var loginAttempt: Boolean = false
        var apiData: ApiLogin
        val creds = Credentials.basic(username, password)
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).header("Authorization", creds).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(
            object : Callback {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    val body: String? = response.body()?.string()
                    val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                    apiData = gson.fromJson(body, ApiLogin::class.java)

                    if (apiData.detail == "Invalid username/password.") {
                        loginAttempt = false
                        println(loginAttempt)
                    } else {
                        loginAttempt = true
                        println(loginAttempt)
                    }
                }


                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please check your connection and try again.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    loginAttempt = false
                }
            })

        return loginAttempt
    }
    class ApiLogin(val detail: String)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your `newCall` method runs async to the main thread meaning the rest of your code keeps running after you call it while it waits on another thread. To fix this rather than returning your result you can handle it in a callback like so:

```
class ApiGet(val url: String, val username: String = Consts.USERNAME, val password: String = Consts.PASSWORD) {

    fun login(completion: (Boolean)->Unit) {

        var loginAttempt: Boolean = false
        var apiData: ApiLogin
        val creds = Credentials.basic(username, password)
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).header("Authorization", creds).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(
            object : Callback {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                    val body: String? = response.body()?.string()
                    val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                    apiData = gson.fromJson(body, ApiLogin::class.java)

                    if (apiData.detail == "Invalid username/password.") {
                        println(loginAttempt)
                        completion(False)
                    } else {
                        print(loginAttempt)
                        completion(True)
                    }
                }


                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please check your connection and try again.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    completion(False)                }
            })
    }
```

You can call the login function like so:

```
ApiGet(url = url,
       username = username.text.toString(),
       password = password.text.toString()).login { result ->

       if (result) {
            // success
       } else {
            // failure
       }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this solution. What's interesting is that now the ApiGet call runs else statement showing the username and password toast message but a second or two later it runs the success result too. very odd

Comment: @Comm4nd0 hmm, are you sure you're not calling it twice?

Comment: worked it out. i had a return false at the bottom of the ApiGet class. removed it and it started working again. thank you so much for this solution! marked as answer.